# Generate Tuple Type using a mapped Type

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

Good morning,

I'm trying to achieve the following,

Create a type that will take the keys from the following object

```
const obj = {
   setName: () => void;
   setAge: () => void;
}
```

And generate a Tuple type using a mapped type that makes

```
[ “setName”, “setAge” ]
```

I might be completely wrong here but for the mapped type I think this would work

```
type MyType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
```

But if T is a type from the object I showcased above, I would end up with the following type

```
type MappedType = {
    setName: () => void;
    setAge: () => void;
}
```

But what I want is

```
type MappedType = [setName, setAge]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats the tuple type look like as you wish ( input and output ) ?

Comment: I have updated the question since I was not clear enough about it, so I apologise

Comment: `type MappedType = [setName, setAge]` as you updated means what ? is it an array tuple of `type MappedType = [() => void, () => void]` or a union types of `(() => void) |  (() => void)` ?

Comment: it means that from the object above "obj" I want to establish a tuple type with the keys of the latter

Comment: from what I saw I need somehow to create a type that represents the union of the keys of the object and from that, a tuple, but I'm struggling to achieve it

Comment: a way to get the `type MappedType = ['setName', 'setAge']` from the obj above ?

Comment: const obj = {
   setName: () => void;
   setAge: () => void;
}
from this object yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need is `UnionToTuple<U>`:

```
// T ====> [...T, E]
type Push<T, E> = T extends any[] ? [...T, E] : [];


// union to intersection of functions
// UnionToIoFn<'a' | 'b'>
// ====> ((x: 'a') => void) & ((x: 'b') => void)
// ====> that equal to { (x: 'a'): void; (x: 'b'): void }
type UnionToIoFn<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: (x: U) => void) => void : never) extends
    ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never



// UnionPop<((x: 'a') => void) & ((x: 'b') => void)> ===> 'b'
// UnionPop<{ (x: 'a'): void; (x: 'b'): void }> ===> 'b'
type UnionPop<F> =
    F extends ({ (x: infer X): void; })
        ? X
        : never;


type UnionToTupleIter<U, Res> =
    [U] extends [never]
        ? Res
        : UnionToTupleIter<
            Exclude<U, UnionPop<UnionToIoFn<U>>> ,
            Push<Res, UnionPop<UnionToIoFn<U>>>
          >


type UnionToTuple<U> = UnionToTupleIter<U, []>;




// test
const obj = {
   setName: () => {},
   setAge: () => {},
}
// You wanted
// type YouWanted = ["setAge", "setName"]
type YouWanted = UnionToTuple<keyof typeof obj>;
```

[click here to try the code in ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBVQXhqD5QG0B0rwBpQFEC6AoAFwE8AHAU1AAUBXAZwAsAeDbBKCUMgDwLIDsAJrVABDPkUQ5QAfiSpkLXKABcSHAG48WkKGp8AlgHs%20oAodD6%20vAE60yAYwJGThgGahXex89p4dAVQNjcEMASUMAMT5GAHIRGNAAH1AYgCMYuD8wWHhQAAo8rlU4mIBKaAQAN0N9AXKAMnzC4vTy3Ora0qzoWAQCehECTgBHahEAG1NzAG98opT40tUOgXU5lrLlmoFQAF9CUgpA5xDwqMZ-NjxQG-z-Th5%20IVFxGXyAa1Vm0H82qu2-qAVipQHwyJUyNZytxeIJfLcmp8LHxXJDQKFAStyrJQiCwRDrFptGBjsZKIYSIwCvMSpiAaBGtSNnTOmwYAg0jFuqS%20OTKbNvrStrU1oLWsKdrs2blOQdyD8gryKYwIlcEREHrDnnkBfNLKjrKAABpLIHbNa7LoIhGyI3Xa03VT4yGaLTEeU8kLgagkcZkUI2C6YABKZFoatuiH8UhhT2EiGd1nwDpuslD8JTqk9hm9vv9gftKduWC49nG1AEZCDCucfIuitOkWilzgCHQhaLVDoTHTmB5dezZ2brcyndAmTdhxrwRzPr9FzY074Xrn%20ch1ckcFdRJ0vFoBDw9mM%209AhlSACtoKBpoW7AQAHIiAC2ZC%20gOmu3btzvAEEAOavvk76fng%20w6AAmoY1CgAA7mIvACN07oUJB1AAOrwWQOzsIgABEv4AbhmD4WQD7PmQuH4MhoCoRhVhYVe2a5vO7xkEQbimIcHFnueW5EkAA)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a Tuple type or is an Array type ok? If you just need `('setName', 'setAge')[]`, you can easily write `(keyof typeof obj)[]`. I don't think it's necessary to make it into an tuple type ([it's definitely possible tho](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues?q=label%3A730+label%3Aanswer)), since I wouldn't rely on the order of object properties, and tuples typically infer a fixed ordering of things in it.

Comment: I kind of explained my question badly, I basically want a type that returns a tuple with the keys of the object I showcase

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro In that case you should definitely check out the link I attached in my answer above. You can simply get a union of all the keys of an object with the `keyof` operator and then converted it into a tuple with any viable solutions you see there.

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks